# Haskell ERROR - Ambiguous type variable `b0' arising from a use of `randoms'

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I am new to haskell and am trying to make a function which will shuffle a list of objects. However, I keep getting ambiguous type errors, I also got one from the 'cmp' function as well.

```
cmp :: Ord b => (a, b) -> (a, b) -> Ordering
cmp (x1,y1) (x2,y2) = compare y1 y2 

--shuffleStack is giving me ambiguous type errors when running, one for randoms and one for cmp
shuffleStack :: StdGen -> [a] -> [a]
shuffleStack g domSet = [x | (x,y) <- sortBy cmp (zip domSet (randoms g))]

--This function nearly does the same thing but doesn't give any errors
test g domSet = sortBy cmp (zip domSet (randoms g))
```

Does anybody know what I am doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: The problem is that now there is no hint what type `b` it should use to generate random numbers.

Comment: Btw, `cmp = comparing snd`

Comment: @damri: you can specify the type of `randoms g`, for example `:: [Int]`, or some other type of random data (that can be compared).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that because you later remove the second element of the 2-tuples, this thus means that the type of the random elements `b`, is not in the signature anymore, and thus can be anything.

You should give it a hint what type to use, for example an `Int`:

```
shuffleStack :: StdGen -> [a] -> [a]
shuffleStack g domSet = [x | (x,y) <- sortBy cmp (zip domSet (randoms g :: [Int]))]
```

Note that you can make use of [**`sortOn :: Ord b => (a -> b) -> [a] -> [a]`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:sortOn):

```
import Data.List(sortOn)

shuffleStack :: StdGen -> [a] -> [a]
shuffleStack g domSet = [x | (x,y) <- sortOn snd (zip domSet (randoms g :: [Int]))]
```

You can also perform a mapping to get rid of the second item of the 2-tuples. We can also swap the order of the items of the 2-tuple to eliminate the *explicit* `domSet` parameter:

```
import Data.List(sortOn)

shuffleStack :: StdGen -> [a] -> [a]
shuffleStack g = map snd . sortOn fst . zip (randoms g :: [Int])
```

For example we can shuffle a list of `Int`s with a seeded pseudo-random generator:

```
Prelude System.Random Data.List> shuffleStack (mkStdGen 0) [1,4,2,5]
[4,5,2,1]
```